# Error with aclocal

Tags: autotools, autoconf

I have an error while trying to run aclocal although i have the Autoconf v 2.67 installed

> configure.ac:6: error: Autoconf version 2.62 or higher is required
>   /usr/share/aclocal-1.11/init.m4:26: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE is expanded from...
>   configure.ac:6: the top level
>   autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 63
>   aclocal: autom4te failed with exit status: 63

and here is the configure.ac file

```
AC_PREREQ(2.59)  
AC_INIT(Header, 1.0, mail@mail.com)   
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE   
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([Header.h])   
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a problem with your PATH.  Or, try setting the environment variable AUTOM4TE to the correct autom4te when you run aclocal:

```
env AUTOM4TE=/path/to/autom4te-2.67 aclocal
```

However, it is typical to not invoke aclocal directly at all; run autoreconf instead.